# Shell refer to second array by value of first one

Tags: arrays, shell, for-loop

I want to make a nested for loop. (on CentOS 6.6 if it matters)

First I have to get trough a list of services. 3 in this example.
Each service can have 1 of more details I want to get trough next.

```
#!/bin/sh

services=(apache ftp ssh)
apache=(detail1 detail2 detail3)
ftp=(detail2 detail3)
ssh=(detail1 detail3 detail5)

for first in ${services[@]}; do
    whatever $first
    for second in ${first[@]}; do
        whatever $second
    done

done
```

But somehow I cannot use `$first[@]` but I can use `$apache[@]`.
Doesn't matter if I use the array's value or a define `$first` by hand without the first array.

Tried multiple suggestions but can't figure it out...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you seems to fetch array values indirectly, so a working code is :

```
#!/bin/bash

services=(apache ftp ssh)
apache=(detail1 detail2 detail3)
ftp=(detail2 detail3)
ssh=(detail1 detail3 detail5)

for first in ${services[@]}; do
    echo "whatever $first"
    for second in $(eval echo \${$first[@]}); do
        echo "whatever $second"
    done
done
```

but `eval` should be avoided, better explain what are you really trying to accomplish, there's maybe a better solution